# Returning a string array containing string forms of integers, replacing multiples of certain numbers with strings of text

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I need to have a function accept two arguments, int start, and int end. I need the two integers to give an integer series. For example, start = 1, end = 10. It would return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. I need the function to return a string array containing the string forms of these numbers, except for multiples of 3, use "FirstName" instead of the number, for multiples of 5 use "LastName", and for multiples of both 3 and 5 use "FullName".

```
public class StringHandler() {
    public static void function(int start, int end) {
        int size = end - start;

        System.out.println("Name - ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("FullName" + " ");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("FirstName" + " ");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.print("LastName" + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(i) + " ");
            }
         }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         function(1, 30);
     }
}
```

Just having a hard coding block right now and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you know that, like OOP suggest, you should use an array or a list of structured objects (like List<Person> where Person has firstName, LastName, and three getters, fullName summing them), do you ? A big String[] with a zillion of random data recognized only by their ordinal position is dangerous and not reusable. What if tomorrow you want to include the "age" too ? you'll have to change the code to search for multiples of 4 etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop should be like this:

```
for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
```

based on:

> For example, start = 1, end = 10. It would return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

---

**EDIT:**

The full source code would be something like this:

```
public static String[] function(int start, int end)
{
    int size = end - start;
    String[] array = new String[size];
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) array[counter] = "FullName";
        else if(i % 3 == 0) array[counter] = "FirstName";
        else if(i % 5 == 0) array[counter] = "LastName";
        else array[counter] = Integer.toString(i);

        if(i < end - 1) array[counter] += " ";
        counter++;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't solve anything, in fact it will make the same exact thing than OP's code.

Comment: How would I return a string array of these integers while replacing the multiples of 3, 5, and both? I believe I have the multiples section handled, just returning the string arrays I don't know if I have right.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri `start` isn't always equal to `1`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad sorry, didn't realize that OP wanted a random start number (believed it would be always 1 looking at his code).

Comment: @AsierAranbarri I set the i = 1; just as an example, my for-loop was wrong. My main problem is returning a string array of these integers while replacing the multiples of 3, 5, and both.

Comment: Why use an external counter when you already have `i`?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl As I said, `start` isn't fixed :)

Comment: Still not necessary to have the additional variable, can just take `start` away from `i`, but I guess it is negligible cost-wise.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl Yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public static String[] function(int start, int end) {
    int size = end - start;

    String[] result = new String[size];

    System.out.println("Name - ");
    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
            result[i-start] = "FullName ";
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            result[i-start] = "FirstName ";
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            result[i-start] = "LastName ";
        } else {
            result[i-start] = Integer.toString(i) + " ";
        }
     }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    return result;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     function(1, 30);
 }
```

The println isn't necessary, just so you can see it in the console. Notice that the return type is no longer `void` but now `String[]`, so you can do something along the lines of:

`String[] stringArray = function(1,30);`

when you call `function` in order to get hold of the resulting array.

Comment: `start` isn't always `1` :)

Comment: My bad, I just copied his code - was a lingering error.